# How to insert two js file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning javascript so forgive me for my questions. I have the task of using it in my HTML file insert two javascript file. The first file I need to connect to the  tags, then another js file I need to set up strictly in the  tags using the .insertAdjacentHTML in which I need to do my job.

Thank you in advance

Comment: And what specific issues did you encounter with your code that you would like to ask about? Because at its current form your question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: I would advice you to go to https://www.w3schools.com and start from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS file by doing the following:

```
<script src="pathToFile"></script>
```

Or you can place your code between the tags like this:

```
<script> your code here </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I placed my first js file in <sctipt> tags, then my job is that in this js file using strictly document.querySelector (''). InsertAdjacentHTML about linking my second js file in the <head> tags

Comment: You might be able to figure it out using the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536452(v=vs.85).aspx